# Option to override logback's logging format in runtime

Tags: java, logging, logback

There are two Java methods doing their debug prints into a single log file (apender).

Is it possible to apply different logging format to different method?

For example...

- `MyClass.someMethod()` prints like `%c - %{foo} %m%n` while
- `MyClass.anotherMethod()` prints like `%c %t %{bar} %m%n%n`.

(These formats shouldn't be hardcoded but instead they are coming from an external source and are subjects of change in runtime.)

Maybe we may set a hook/listener or something like that...

Environment: Java 7+ / logback-core:0.9.28 / logback-classic:0.9.28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As  by [layout docs](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html) we can define a custom layout in `logback.xml`:

```
<appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
 <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
  <layout class="com.me.MyLayout" />
 </encoder>
</appender>
```

A custom layout implementation can make its decision basing on MDC:

```
public class MyLayout extends LayoutBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    public String doLayout(ILoggingEvent event) {
        if ("foo".equals(MDC.get("method"))) {
            return "a custom message for method `foo`\n";
        } else {
            return "a default message from my own layout\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
MDC.put("method", "foo");
log.info("a from method foo");
```